# How to get the contentSize of a web page in Qt5.4-QtWebEngine

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I'm using the new Qt5.4 with the module QtWebEngine and from what I see mainFrame() doesn't exists anymore. How to get the contentSize/size of the page and how to render it now? I tried with the setView and view but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any native Qt method for that, but I came up with a workaround:
once the page is loaded, I do the following to resize my widget to the web content:

```
webView->page()->runJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollWidth;",[=](QVariant result){
int newWidth=result.toInt()+10;
webView->resize(newWidth,webView->height());
});

webView->page()->runJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight;",[=](QVariant result){
int newHeight=result.toInt();
webView->resize(webView->width(),newHeight);
});
```

NB: I added a 10px width margin

Comment: Indeed, after a lot of trial&error, looks like the only way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `QWebEnginePage::geometryChangeRequested` **signal** does what you want.

Also you display a `QWebEnginePage` by creating a `QWebEngineView` (it's a `QWidget`) and calling `QWebEngineView::setPage(yourPage)`.